# How use Material framework in XCode's IB?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, material-design, gui-builder

I'm Trying include Material framework (https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/) components in my project using XCode UIBuilder, but every element has some type of issue when I run the application.
[image: Expectations and reality] 
On the left side is what I have in UIBuilder; and how I expect to see Material elements (I mean colors, fonts, etc). On the right side is what I have when I run the app.
When I use Material components from code - it is all fine.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.